# Focusing the last ListBoxItem in code-behind

Tags: wpf

I'm adding a new item to my `ObservableCollection` which is used as `listBox.ItemsSource`:

```
ObservableCollection<MySrc> mySrc;
// in window constructor
mySrc = App.Database.GetSrc();
listBox.ItemsSource = mySrc;
```

When a button is clicked, I'd like to add new item to the ObservableCollection and also focus the newly added item. My control template  contains `TextBox` element. I'd like the TextBox to get a Cursor (This happens if it gets focus by default)

```
    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MySrcnewMatch = MySrc.PopulateMySrc("Default name", true, true);
        this.mySrc.Add(mySrc);

        listBox.SelectedIndex = listBox.Items.Count-1;
        ((ListBoxItem)listBox.SelectedItem).Focus();
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Namespace.Model.MySrc' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.
```

What is the correct way to focus the last `ListBoxItem` in `ListBox`

Comment: If I use the code in that answer, I get Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Binding.exe
**listBoxItem** was null.

Comment: It must be visible. Try ScrollIntoView or disable ListBox virtualization. And probably do a bit more own research before asking.

Comment: Thanks. I'd probably got a runtime error for not scrolling into view at some point in the future. As of now, listBox.UpdateLayout(); was the missing part.

Comment: And I'll try a a few more keywords before posting in the future. I just read 800 pages of Pro WPF 4.5 and there is still an enormous amount of basic knowledge missing. I guess mostly because the focus is on XAML instead of code.